# how to share data between many ViewControllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am new to Swift

I wanted to know that is there anyway in swift to store some data which could be accessed by many ViewControllers instead of using Segues or delegates.

Just like we store some data to databases and later access them easily

Comment: you can use `NSUserDefaults ` . store small data like strings and all with a key and you can access it throughout your app.

Comment: Why do you not want to use segues or delegates? Those are probably the best ways to share data between `UIViewController`s as it makes it easy to then reuse those view controllers.

Comment: I actually want to create a session to store user's info like it's username-name, contact-details , ID & password so that I could access it anywhere required which could be terminated whenever user close the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use NSUserDefaults if the data is small and you want it across application invocation.

If you want your data to be transient then it is good idea to have a simple singleton model class. A simple Swift class that holds your data that could be accessed by many View Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to share data between view controllers like  `NSUserDefaults`, `CoreData`, with a `plist`:

1. `NSUserDefaults:`The NSUserDefaults class acts very much like something called a Property List (aka plist).  It may be just a fancy interface for a plist, or it may be more, I’m not entirely sure.  Nonetheless, plists are limited in what kind of objects they can store. More info [HERE](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/).
2. `CoreData:` The Core Data stack consists of a set of objects that facilitate saving and retrieving information from Core Data. There’s an object to manage the Core Data state as a whole, an object representing the data model, and so on. More Info [HERE](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift).
3. `plist:` Property lists are a way of structuring arbitrary data and accessing it at runtime. An information property list is a specialized type of property list that contains configuration data for a bundle. The keys and values in the file describe the various behaviors and configuration options you want applied to your bundle. Xcode typically creates an information property list file for any bundle-based projects automatically and configures an initial set of keys and values with appropriate default values. You can edit the file, however, to add any keys and values that are appropriate for your project or change the default values of existing keys.More Info [HERE](http://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/).